# Finding the closest set of coordinates using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, coordinates

I have 2 tables; Table 1 has the lat/long coordinates for a list of 15,000 Stops and Table 2 has the lat/long coordinates for 450 addresses. My goal is to identify which stop is closest to each of the addresses by using those coordinates. This is how the tables are set up

Table 1: Stops

| Stop # (col A) | Latitude (col B) | Longitude (col C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40.7182 | -74.00018 |
| 2 | 41.82027 | -87.6032 |
| 3 | 34.05255 | -118.242 |
| 4 | 27.59021 | -80.29301 |
| 5 | 39.82039 | -89.62517 |

Table 2: Addresses

| Address # (col G) | Latitude (col H) | Longitude (col I) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43.05439 | -87.8958 |
| 2 | 44.97301 | -93.0379 |
| 3 | 32.90127 | -98.9361 |
| 4 | 28.74312 | -79.1028 |
| 5 | 33.69102 | -83.1266 |

I've tried a bunch of different combinations, and this is the function that has been the closest:

```
INDEX(A$2:A$17986, SUMPRODUCT((MIN(SQRT((B$2:B$17986 - H2)^2 + (C$2:C$17986 - I2)^2)) = SQRT((B$2:B$17986 - H2)^2 + (C$2:C$17986 - I2)^2)) * ROW(A$2:A$17986))
```

The function operates without error, but the results were way off when I manually checked them. I've gone over the formula to see what is off but can't figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: First thought is you would have a matrix of 6.75 million rows, which is a cartesian join of stops and addresses. Wouldn't be difficult to write a power query with a formula such as: `ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Stop_Latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(90-Address_Latitude))  +SIN(RADIANS(90-Stop_Latitude)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-Address_Latitude)) *COS(RADIANS(Stop_Longitude-Address_Longitude))) *3959 as distance` however; ACOS is not supported in power query. Not sure how to substitute that. At any rate, a SQL equivalent **should** be easy if you can shape it like that.

Comment: Your approach uses Pythagoras, which implies you aren't covering distances where you need to take converging lines of longitude into account.  Is this correct?  Over the coordinate distances your example data shows, your spherical errors would become huge.  Over distances inside a county or metro area, they would be almost insignificant.  Some of your samples are thousands of miles apart.  Also, if you have access to Excel O365 this is actually a whole lot simpler than it looks.  I created a solution in a couple of minutes using dynamic arrays, with no helper tables, they are a game changer.